# Count() does not return zero MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am a web developer and tried to search for the solution on a mysql query.I am unable to get the right solution for the count() function to return zero.
The count() function doesnot return zero for all dates.

The query is as below . can anyone help me on this.

```
SELECT
    count(stat_id) as typeSuccess,
    device_type as typeName,
    YEARWEEK(date_auth) as date
FROM auth_stat
WHERE
    AUTH_RESULT = 'SUCCESS' AND
    date_auth BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 6 WEEK) AND CURDATE()
GROUP BY YEARWEEK(date_auth), device_type
ORDER BY YEARWEEK(date_auth)
```

The query that i tried to form is

```
select
    date_auth,
    count(stat_id) as typeSuccess,
    device_type as typeName,
    YEARWEEK(date_auth) as date
from
( 
    select @curDate := Date_Add(@curDate, interval 1 day) as MyJoinDate
    from
    ( 
        select @curDate := CURDATE()
    ) sqlvars, auth_stat limit 18 
) dateAll
LEFT JOIN auth_stat U on dateAll.MyJoinDate = U.date_auth
group by dateAll.MyJoinDate
```

Actual ouput :

```
+------------+-------------+
| date       | typeSuccess |
+------------+-------------+
| 2015-03-18 |          11 |
+------------+-------------+
```

### Expected Output:

```
+------------+-------------+
| date       | typeSuccess |
+------------+-------------+
| 2015-03-18 |          11 |
| 2015-03-19 |          0  |
| 2015-03-20 |          0  |
+------------+-------------+
```

Comment: The inner select is *not returning any rows* for those dates and counting nothing is .. well, not counting at all .. as there are *no* rows to count for the given group (read: *the groups do not exist*). You have to perform a left join on the date and default the typeSuccess to 0 or otherwise synthesize the *missing* rows.

Comment: What is the first query for?

Comment: Which table has all dates you want to appear in the expected output (with or without a COUNT of 0)?

Comment: how about some data? if you are trying to count something i would start with just a regular select without a Cartesian Product. I don't get the point of the variable since the process order of those is not guarenteed

Comment: Jayant if my answer solved your issue can you please accept it? it is the check mark underneath the number of votes for an answer. if you could it would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

I believe all you want to do is just this

```
SELECT
    SUM(AUTH_RESULT='SUCCESS') as numSuccess,
    YEARWEEK(date_auth) as date
FROM auth_stat
WHERE date_auth BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 6 WEEK) AND CURDATE()
GROUP BY YEARWEEK(date_auth), device_type
ORDER BY YEARWEEK(date_auth)
```

basically all i'm doing is telling MySQL to sum up the boolean value (0 or 1) when auth_result is a success.. `SUM()` will return a 0 for a particular week if there is no successes in that week

The main issue is you were filtering out all non successful auth_results which would then not be counted. so remove that from the where and you should be good!

if you want it per day then you can do this

```
SELECT
    SUM(AUTH_RESULT='SUCCESS') as numSuccess,
    DATE(date_auth) as date
FROM auth_stat
WHERE date_auth BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 6 WEEK) AND CURDATE()
GROUP BY DATE(date_auth), device_type
ORDER BY DATE(date_auth)
```

[**SQLFIDDLE FOR BOTH RESULTS**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f3657/1)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT COUNT(statid), dates.auth_date 
FROM 
(   SELECT DISTINCT auth_date 
    FROM Table1 
    WHERE auth_date BETWEEN '2015-03-06' AND '2015-03-09' -- or whatever
) AS dates
LEFT JOIN Table1 ON TRUE
 AND Table1.auth_date = dates.auth_date
 AND table1.auth_result = 'SUCCESS'
GROUP BY dates.auth_date
ORDER BY dates.auth_date
```

as desribed here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/84faf/2
for eg data:

```
+--------+-------------+------------+
| statid | auth_result | auth_date  |
+--------+-------------+------------+
|      1 | SUCCESS     | 2015-03-05 |
|      2 | SUCCESS     | 2015-03-05 |
|      3 | SUCCESS     | 2015-03-05 |
|      4 | OTHER       | 2015-03-06 |
|      5 | OTHER       | 2015-03-06 |
|      6 | OTHER       | 2015-03-06 |
|      7 | SUCCESS     | 2015-03-07 |
|      8 | SUCCESS     | 2015-03-07 |
|      9 | SUCCESS     | 2015-03-07 |
|     10 | OTHER       | 2015-03-08 |
|     11 | SUCCESS     | 2015-03-08 |
|     12 | OTHER       | 2015-03-08 |
|     13 | SUCCESS     | 2015-03-09 |
|     14 | SUCCESS     | 2015-03-09 |
|     15 | SUCCESS     | 2015-03-09 |
|     16 | OTHER       | 2015-03-10 |
|     17 | OTHER       | 2015-03-10 |
|     18 | SUCCESS     | 2015-03-10 |
|     19 | OTHER       | 2015-03-11 |
+--------+-------------+------------+
```

eg output:

```
+---------------+-------------------------+
| count(statid) |        auth_date        |
+---------------+-------------------------+
|             0 | March, 06 2015 00:00:00 |
|             3 | March, 07 2015 00:00:00 |
|             1 | March, 08 2015 00:00:00 |
|             3 | March, 09 2015 00:00:00 |
+---------------+-------------------------+
```

Comment: you can very easily just use the output in a table builder like this one to format it for you :) http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html  -------------- btw you have invalid syntax in your answer incase you want to fix that for the OP

Answer (score 0):

It is not beautiful but hope it helps:

```
SELECT
    date_auth,
    count(stat_id) as typeSuccess,
    device_type as typeName,
    YEARWEEK(date_auth) as date
FROM
( 
    SELECT 
   DATE(DATE_ADD(NOW(), interval tmp.id day)) AS MyJoinDate
   FROM (SELECT 1 as id
         UNION ALL SELECT 2
         UNION ALL SELECT 3
         UNION ALL SELECT 4
         UNION ALL SELECT 5
         UNION ALL SELECT 6
         UNION ALL SELECT 7
         UNION ALL SELECT 8
         UNION ALL SELECT 9
         UNION ALL SELECT 10
         UNION ALL SELECT 11
         UNION ALL SELECT 12
         UNION ALL SELECT 13
         UNION ALL SELECT 14
         UNION ALL SELECT 15
         UNION ALL SELECT 16
         UNION ALL SELECT 17
         UNION ALL SELECT 18
   ) AS tmp 
) dateAll
LEFT JOIN auth_stat U on dateAll.MyJoinDate = U.date_auth
group by dateAll.MyJoinDate
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried adding the query as below. It stills returns me records that have the counts and not the dates with the count as zero.

```
SELECT COUNT(stat_id), dates.date_auth 
FROM 
(   SELECT DISTINCT date_auth 
    FROM auth_stat 
    WHERE date_auth BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 20 DAY) AND       CURDATE()
) AS dates
LEFT JOIN auth_stat ON TRUE
 AND auth_stat.date_auth = dates.date_auth
 AND auth_stat.auth_result = 'SUCCESS'
GROUP BY dates.date_auth
ORDER BY dates.date_auth
```

Output result for the above query:

COUNT(stat_id)  date_auth Ascending 1
1   2015-03-05 00:00:00
1   2015-03-06 00:00:00
11  2015-03-18 00:00:00